# Laravel IDE Helper Not Working After Upgrade PhpStorm 10

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I was using [barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) in phpstorm 9. Yesterday i download new version of phpstorm. I imported configuration files.

But i saw that laravel-ide-helper is not working after upgrade phpstorm 10. Do you know any idea about that ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried cleaning out the system caches? On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.